# Java: Changing Player Number

Tags: java

I am writing a method to switch the player number after each player's turn. I am using a boolean array that keeps track of the players still playing (that have not been eliminated). So the array at the beginning of the game is initialized to true and is the size of the number of players in the game. As players get eliminated, the corresponding value of the index gets set to false (For example if Player 2 gets eliminated, the third index of the array gets set to false). (Note: Player 0 does exist, so if two players are playing they are Players 0 and Player 1.) If the player number is equal to the last player, then it needs to start back at the beginning and find the first player that is still in the game. Otherwise, the player number increments to the first player that is still playing. Here is what I have:

```
public static int switchPlayer(int currentPlayer, boolean[] playerList) {
    if(currentPlayer == playerList.length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if(playerList[i] == true) {
                currentPlayer = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i = (currentPlayer+1); i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if(playerList[i] == true) {
                currentPlayer = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentPlayer;
}
```

Any changes or suggestions? It is not quite working and cannot see where it is going wrong.

I have tried to implement one of the answers, but I cannot figure out how to get it implemented. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Players 0,1,2,3. Then length is 4.
But the argument `currentPlayer` can only have 0-3 value, since thats the player numbers, so try changing this:

```
if(currentPlayer == playerList.length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        if(playerList[i] == true) {
            currentPlayer = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
if(currentPlayer + 1 == playerList.length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        if(playerList[i] == true) {
            currentPlayer = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow...Brilliant! I knew there was something small that I was overlooking. That fixed the problem and that makes sense. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you use an ArrayList data structure where you store all players that are currently not eliminated. So when a player is eliminated you remove that object from the ArrayList. This way you wouldn't need to use boolean to keep track of player status.

```
public static int switchPlayer(int currentPlayer, ArrayList playerList) {
    // move to the next player
    currentPlayer++;

    // reset back to the first player if we reached the end player
    if(currentPlayer >= playerList)
        currentPlayer = 0;

    return currentPlayer;
}
```

Now originally, in some part of your code I think you are setting the value "false" to indicate that the user has been eliminated. However, my idea is to remove the eliminated player. For example, if you want the second player to be eliminated, then you can do something like this in an array list:

```
list.remove(2);
```

Comment: I see what you are thinking, but logically that is complicated because if one of the middle players is eliminated, then performing the actual action of switching players is difficult to implement. I tried it, but ended up reverting back because I could not see how to implement it in actual code.

Comment: I am not sure if that is complicated, you usually use an "index" to currently point whose turn. So when an element is removed, then you maintain the "index" value which currently points now to the next player to move.

Comment: Can you help me out please? There will be the currentPlayer passed in as well as the arraylist. I am just really struggling with the implementation for some reason. There can be multiple players who are eliminated and if the last player is eliminated, then the last player who is still playing will change. If the current player is the last player still playing, then the current player will change back to first player still playing.

Comment: Well I'd like to help you on this through sample code but I cannot code here in the comments section. Try finding me through my profile.

Comment: What do you mean by finding you through your profile? Are you going to post it somewhere on there?

Comment: What if at some point though, player 0 gets eliminated before the end of the game? Won't the currentPlayer=0 be invalid then? That's why I am having a hard time, it needs to set the currentPlayer to the first player that is still playing.

Comment: I really appreciate all of the time and effort you put into this. Jaanus found the solution using my original implementation, so I will go with that. I really do appreciate your efforts though.