# Use array to decide who is active player (turn based guessing game)

Tags: java, arrays

I am using a method (as shown below) that allows me to input the amount of players along with a name for each player. Is there a way for me to use this array to decide who is the active player? (turn based guessing game). If you could just point me in the right direction.

```
public class Program {
     String[] playerList;
     int playersAmount = 0;

      public void inputPlayers() {
          playersAmount = Input.readInt();
          playerList= new String[playersAmount];
          for (int g = 0; g < playersAmount; g++) {
              String namePlayer = "player " + (g+1);
              playerList [g] = namePlayer;
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Note: I forgot to translate 1 of the names in there, fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean by "amount of players" .. is this "Number of players" ?

Comment: @Deepak That's right, English is not my native language, sorry.

Comment: If player has properties like name and state, then why don't you create Class Player?

Comment: I wouldn't know how, I'm still quite new to java, trying to get a hang of the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look over the question I had about changing the player number. I think this exactly what you are looking for (or something similar): [Java: Changing Player Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505261/java-changing-player-number)

Essentially I used a boolean array to keep track of who is still playing where the array index corresponds to the player number a[0] = Player 0, a[1] = Player 1, etc. If a player gets eliminated mark the corresponding index with false: `a[i] = false;` You can then use the following method (taken from my question) to switch the player number to the next player still playing:

```
public static int switchPlayer(int currentPlayer, boolean[] playerList) {
    // if the current player + 1 = length (size) of array,
    // start back at the beginning and find the first player still playing
    if(currentPlayer + 1 == playerList.length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if(playerList[i] == true) {    // if player is still in the game
                currentPlayer = i;         // currentPlayer = current index of array
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // otherwise the current player number + 1 is not at the end of the array
    // i.e. it is less than the length (size) of the array, so find the next player
    // still playing
    else {
        for(int i = (currentPlayer+1); i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if(playerList[i] == true) {
                currentPlayer = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentPlayer;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about my code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options in my opinion.

1. create a Player object with instance variables as his name and a boolean that states whether or not he is active.
2. You can create a boolean array that is sync with the player array that states wether or not the player is active.

ex for 2

```
boolean[] activeStatus= new boolean[1];
String[] players = new String[1];
activeStatus[0]=true;
players[0]="Joe Smith";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to represent the current player you can use a int

```
int curplayer = 0;
```

Every time their round is done you can add one to get the index of the next player.

```
curplayer++;
```

As for it returning to the first player after the last player, I suggest you look into the % (modulo) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the turn number using an instance variable:

```
private int turn;
```

Increment it every turn:

```
turn++;
```

The index of the player whose turn it is can be calculated by using the remainder of dividing the turn by the number of players:

```
int playerIndex = turn % playersAmount;
```

I leave it to you to work these parts into your code.

Comment: Should I be using something like while (playerIndex < 0)?

Answer (score 0):

My java is a bit rusty, but something like the following should work.

```
i = 0
while (playing == True)
{
    player = playerList[i]
    i = (i + 1) % playerList.length

    [Do something]
}
```